# Understanding REST parameters in google-search-api

Tags: python, rest, google-search-api

To automatically download image URLs found through googles' search API, I need to be able to programmatically generate relevant search queries in my script.

The search url I currently use in my python script looks like this:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + quote(
                    search_term) + '&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch' + params + '&sa=X&ei=XosDVaCXD8TasATItgE&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg'
```

Which works well if I use simple or combined queries like

```
search_term = "Cats AND -Dogs"
```

When I enter "cats" in google and switch to the images tab, I see the following panel of term-buttons, right above the first images of adorable kittens:

[image]

Clicking on the buttons "cute","anime" and "love" e.g. changes the search url to

```
https://www.google.de/search?tbm=isch&q=cats&chips=q:cats,g_1:anime,g_2:cute,g_8:love&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6ra6-v7bZAhXEvhQKHR4UCYsQ4lYIOCgA&biw=1536&bih=386&dpr=1
```

Now to use that feature in my script, I need to understand the following things:

1. In what way does selecting one of the buttons refine or complement my search? Is this a successive refinement of search terms, or a logical combination?
2. The parameter names g_1, g_2 and g_8 in the url above imply some kind of hierarchical ordering. but what do they actually stand for?